# Why does Eclipse shrink projects better than Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, proguard

I used to use Eclipse with ADT for programming Android. Yesterday I moved to Android Studio (after a full clean-up of my PC). I imported an entire project I'm working on, and after having some issuses with libraries and dependecies, I finally compiled it.

I enabled **proguard** in app's build.gradle (not in libraries), and then I tried to export a **signed APK**. In Eclipse, this project's APK was about **150 kb**. Android Studio **generated a 750 kb file**...

Does **Android Studio** uses **Proguard** worse than **Eclipse**? I have no idea...

EDIT
I decompiled the APK using an online tool.
Looks like java code got obfuscated, but resources haven't been touched

Comment: Have you enabled shrink resources in gradle file??

Comment: I setted "minifyEnabled" to true in my app build.gradle file

Comment: Try `shrinkResources true` and `minifyEnabled true` to obfuscate code and shrink resources http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking

Comment: now I have a 708 kb apk ;)

Comment: It should be same check if the build variant is release or debug

Comment: Build variant is release

Comment: how about your min support version? in Android Studio they are specified in build.gradle instead of Manifest file.

Comment: minSdkVersion is 8. Does it change anything?